# How to get/filter the latest value of a field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, max, django-queryset, getlatest

I have models as below:

```
class ProjectRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='user_projects')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_projects')
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=(("project_a","A"),("project_b","B")),null=True)
    version = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to filter the latest value of version with this:

```
project = list(ProjectRecord.objects.filter(
    user=self.request.user, project_type='project_a'
))
```

But I don't know how to achieve it.the data in database is similar as below:

```
id project_id version project_type
1   5          1.0      project_a
2   5          1.0      project_b
3   4          1.0      project_a
4   4          1.0      project_b
5   5          2.0      project_a          
6   5          2.0      project_b
7   5          3.0      project_a
8   5          3.0      project_b
```

For example, I want to get the latest value of `project_id=5` to exact match other data and do not delete other `project_id`'s value if their versions are not updated, the `queryset` should be display as below

```
id project_id version project_type
1   4          1.0      project_a
2   4          1.0      project_b
3   5          3.0      project_a
4   5          3.0      project_b
```

Comment: So for every `project_type` and `project_id`, you want the maximum version?

Comment: Please do not use `### text`, this is meant for *heads* (like `<h3>...</h3>`) to write subtitles.

Comment: I understood now, thanks Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use annotation with `Max`:

```
from django.db.models import Max

ProjectRecord.objects.filter(
    user=self.request.user,
    project_type='project_a'
).values(
    'project_id', 'project_type'
).annotate(
    max_version=Max('version')
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt answer, it seems like working, but on the front end, I can't get the name and datetime of project with userproject.project.name and userproject.project.name or any other changes, it has displayed normally before.

Comment: @Begin2Pip Unfortunatly `values('project_id', 'project_type')` will limit fields you have access to `'project_id', 'project_type'`. So in case you need project detals you need to do additional query. Alternatively you can try to add required fields as values arguments directly: `values('project_id', 'project__name', 'project__datetime', 'project_type')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I want to display project.version too, only projectrecord.version, not projectrecord.project.version, I found this also limit field of version, right

Comment: @Begin2Pip You are welcome. Not sure I understand you right. but instead of `version` you can access `max_version` field, which was annotated to the queryset.

Comment: neverwalkaloner Yes, yes, max_version is right, thank you so so so much,